# Overstaying Schengen Visa for 1 day

Tags: visas, schengen, overstaying

I was in Germany last September, my visa said I had 14 days to stay in the Schengen area.

When I was leaving back for Egypt the passport control officer noticed that I was leaving on the 15th day. I didn't even realise that as I had written previously in my visa application that I was staying for 15 days and the embassy in Cairo had my complete airline ticket with specific dates.

Anyway the officer just filed a report on the incident but didn't stamp my passport with my exit date from the Schengen area.

Do any of you guys know if that would make it harder for me to be granted a visa in the future?

Comment: One interpretation is that the officer gave you a break.

Comment: Hi Omar i had almost the same situation .. i was denied boarding on my original flight cause i was missing PCR and booked on the next day a new flight and by then my visa was one day expired … Can you please tell me how it went and if you were denied a Schengen visa in future ?

Comment: would be nice to have an update from OP if he ever did have trouble reentering the EU, but I guess that'd be too much to ask for as it looks like he's never been back to the site.

Answer (score 9):

You're not going to get a definitive answer on this, because the official guidelines on this are not public.  That said...

You're *probably* OK.  Your overstay was recorded, but you were not fined, banned or deported, so it's not a huge black mark on your record.

However, your overstay will most likely show up when they examine your previous visas, so you should attach a letter with your next visa application explaining in simple terms what happened: you applied for 15 days to match flight dates, visa was only granted for 14, but you did not notice.

Good luck!

Comment: (+1) An old answer and the advice is generally sound but note that there is actually no Schengen-wise system to merely record an overstay. For now, until the EES comes online, either there is a ban (i.e. an alert for refusal of entry and stay under article 24 of regulation 2018/1861) or there is no record (or at most a national record) and no way for a consulate to look up record of (over)stays in other member states. What might trip up the OP is the lack of stamp.