Consequences of overstaying Schengen visa
Background:
In summer 2023, I visited Germany for work from USA on Schengen short term visa. My flight back from Germany was via Poland and it so happened that the flight was cancelled in Krakow, Poland and no flights on that day were available. The airlines put me on a flight the next day but this meant that I overstayed my Schengen visa by one day.
The rescheduled return flight was via Germany (again) and I was stopped by the border police in Germany and a case was registered against me for illegally entering and overstaying my Schengen Visa. I received a bunch of paperwork along with the contact of a public defendant, who will be handling my case. I was informed earlier this year that my case has been dropped and I will not have to pay a fine.
I have travelled multiple times in the last seven years to the Schengen territory and this is the first time such an incident has happened with me.
Questions:
a) I am now applying for Schengen short term visa for visiting Spain for work, will this incident have any affect on me getting the visa? Presently the Schengen visa application form does not require any information about previous overstays. Do I have to inform the Consulate of Spain of this incident?
b) I will be applying for a Schengen D-type visa in Italy in October for work, will this have any affect on getting the visa? Do I have to inform the Consulate of Italy of this incident?
Note that I am not applying via the German consulate, the country where my overstay happened.

Seems like you asked this question before too ?

No, this is my first post on this website. If there is an exact duplicate question, that's a coincidence and it would help me a lot if you can point it out.

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22849/overstaying-schengen-visa-for-1-day

What stamps do you have in your passport as a result of this situation? What did the public defendant advise about disclosing it in any future visa applications?

The stamps in your passport should make it obvious that you overstayed to anyone who bothers counting the days. Did you keep any evidence of the original flight and the fact it was cancelled?

IMHO You didn't overstay: if charges were cancelled nothing should remain on the record. Probably the defendant make clear you didn't intent to overstay: it was caused by external events out of your control (and not foreseeable within acceptable probabilities). IMHO you are cleared. Just next time try to have some buffer, else doubts my arrise

Yeah... make sure you've got several extra days at the end of your stay beyond your intended departure date, just in case.

Update: I got my short term Schengen visa for Spain without disclosing anything about this issue. It seems there is no record or these records are not shared with partner EU countries.

@Traveller It so happened that, on the day of flight cancellation, I had already passed through the border control at Poland. Once it was clear, we were not flying that day, the border police at Krakow again cancelled the stamp. Next day I received the stamp as usual. The public defendant did not say anything about the future applications.

@jcaron I have kept the documents.

@GiacomoCatenazzi I think I agree with your statement. I had not said anything about this in my cover letter to the consulate and received the short term visa in the usual time.
